# Disown a private organization repo on GitHub

Tags: github

I still own and contributed to a few private repos in an organization account of my former job. Currently I don't have access to these repos, but keep getting notifications from them. Is there a way to disown or remove myself from these repos? Going to ["Repositories" in Settings](https://github.com/settings/repositories) doesn't help, as these repos are not listed there.

Comment: Are you still a member of that github organization?

Comment: @larsks I am not and that’s the problem